# Leaflet map not returning JSON data from web service

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a web service that queries a database and returns JSON data. I also have a HTML page which has AJAX and a Leaflet map. I have to make the map display markers based on the JSON that returns from the web service.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, I have followed the class notes. I think the problem is the request is not sending. Here is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Points of Interest</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skeleton.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/wad/leaflet/leaflet.css' />

<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wad/leaflet/leaflet.js'></script>


</head>
<body onload='init()'>
  <img src="heroxd.jpg" alt="">

<div class="container">
  <div class="twelve-columns">
        <h1>Welcome to Points of Interest!</h1>
        <p>Linking users to interesting areas for 25 years</p>
        <p>Enter a region below to search for POIs!</p>
        <input type="text" id="region" class="margin-top-30" placeholder="Enter Region" name="region" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </div>
    <div id="jsonload">

    </div>

    <div id="map1" style="width:800px; height:600px">
      <div id="info"></div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var map;
var attrib;

function init()
{
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", poiMarkers);
    map = L.map ("map1");
    attrib="Map data copyright OpenStreetMap contributors, Open Database Licence";

    L.tileLayer
        ("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            { attribution: attrib } ).addTo(map);

    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (processPosition, handleError,
                    {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge: 5000 }
                                        );
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Sorry, geolocation not supported in this browser");
    }

    function processPosition(gpspos)
    {
        var info = 'Lat: ' + gpspos.coords.latitude + ' lon: ' + gpspos.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info;



        map.setView([gpspos.coords.latitude,gpspos.coords.longitude], 14);
    }

    function handleError(err)
    {
        alert('An error occurred: ' + err.code);
    }
}








function processPosition(gpspos)
{
    var info = 'Lat: ' + gpspos.coords.latitude + ' lon: ' + gpspos.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info;



    map.setView([gpspos.coords.latitude,gpspos.coords.longitude], 14);
}

function handleError(err)
{
    alert('An error occurred: ' + err.code);
}

function poiMarkers()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('region').value;
  var ajaxConnection = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxConnection.addEventListener ("load",e =>
      {
        var allPlaces = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
        var lat = 0;
            var lon = 0;
        var poiLocation = "";

        allPlaces.forEach( curplace =>
          {
            lat = `${curPlace.lat}`;
            lon = `${curPlace.lon}`;
            poiLocation = [lat, lon];
            L.marker(poiLocation).addTo(map);
          } );
      });



  // Open the connection to a given remote URL.
  ajaxConnection.open("GET" , `https://****return_poi.php?region=${a}`);

  // Send the request.
  ajaxConnection.send();
}
```

Comment: I urge you to follow: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: There is a high chance your whole page reloads when you clcik on your submit button. Look for `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://****return_poi.php?region=${a}",
  data: data,
  type: "GET",
  success: success,
  dataType: json
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

or

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp